# (VB) How to allow a clicked picturebox to know which part of the array it is?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox, minesweeper

I'm trying to make a minesweeper game as a project in vb but I can't figure this bit out, any help is appreciated.

I have a grid of 100 pictureboxes on a form, and then code to randomly choose several places in an 10x10 array to mark as "bomb" (as a string at the minute). My problem is that I don't know how to relate the box that was clicked to it's place in the array.

I know how to use DirectCast, but have not been able to implement that in this case. I had also thought about trying to use the pictureboxes as objects, but am not sure how that works.

Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: 100 PictureBoxes is a lot. One way to know the position of each PictureBox  would be to store the position in the PictureBox's Tag property. For example, set the Tag property of the top left PictureBox to `New Point(0, 0)`.

Comment: use the tag property to mark them with a R:C code as the identifier.

Comment: One way would be to embed the position in the **Name** property of each PB (then parse it in the click handler).  Another would be to generate the PBs at **run-time** and store their position in the **Tag** property or externally somehow (like through a **Dictionary** or something else).  Yet another approach would be to place the PBs in a **TableLayoutPanel** so you could use its [GetPositionFromControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getpositionfromcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Parsing in the click handler sounds like a good idea. How would I go about doing this? Sorry, I have little experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One way would be to embed the position in the Name property of each PB
> (then parse it in the click handler).
>
> Parsing in the click handler sounds like a good idea. How would I go
> about doing this? Sorry, I have little experience.

You could simply name all of the PictureBoxes with the same prefix, then the row and column; with those three parts separated with an underscore.  For instance, the PictureBox in row 2, column 3, could be named "pb_2_3".

Now you can use a common handler and `String.Split()` to retrieve the row/column:

```
Private Sub pbs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pb_2_3.Click, pb_2_4.Click
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    If pb.Name.ToLower.StartsWith("pb_") Then
        Dim values() As String = pb.Name.Split("_")
        If values.Length = 3 Then
            Dim row As Integer = CInt(values(1))
            Dim col As Integer = CInt(values(2))

            Debug.Print(String.Format("Name: {0}, Row: {1}, Col: {2}", pb.Name, row, col))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously this means you'll have to rename all 100 of your PictureBoxes by hand...not fun; but you'd also have to do that if you used the Tag() property approach as well.

Comment: That looks like it'll work, thank you so much for your help! I'll give it a try, but I understand how it should work.